# How to identify unique values from a csv with row breaks in R

Tags: r, csv, unique

I have a csv with a line break that I import to R using the `read.csv` feature and I want to identify the unique values in one of the columns.  For example my example.csv file looks like this:

[image: example.csv file]

I believe I can use `unique` after I delete the empty row which I do like this:

```
df <- read.csv(file = "example.csv",header = FALSE)

colnames(df)[1:2] <- c("path","group")
df <- df[!(df$path=="" | df$group==""), ]


unique_groups <- unique(df$group)
```

However, `unique_groups` (despite only having 3 different groups), turns out to be a factor with 4 levels, my 3 different groups and then blank or "".

I have figured out that if I save `df` as a csv right before the `unique_groups` step and the read back in that csv, it works fine and then `unique_groups` is a factor with 3 levels, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this?  Am I doing something wrong with the initial import or how I remove the blank row?

Any help is appreciated - thanks!

Comment: When I run your code on a similarly structured dataset it correctly shows 3 different values.

Comment: Anyway, I would suggest using the `remove_empty_rows()` function from package `janitor` after you import csv.

Comment: Interesting, I guess it's something strange on my end.  I also can't get `df <- remove_empty(dat = df, which = "rows", quiet = FALSE)` to work so I guess I'll just do some more digging.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out when I imported my csv, it was classifying column B as a factor which was causing my problems.  So now I just import it as a character class and that has resolved my issue, like so:

```
df <- read.csv(file = "example.csv",header = FALSE, colClasses = c("character","character"))
```